# Geolocation: How do I set conditional markers on the Leaflet view?

Tags: 8, hooks

I'm using Geolocation to list about 20 pubs / restaurants, but I'd like the user to be able to know if the address is a restaurant or a pub just by seeing the icon.

When I created my content type, I added a boolean (radio type) to let the admin choose between "restaurant" and "pub". The issue now is that I don't really know how I should proceed. I found [this module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ip_geoloc) but it's limited to Drupal 7.

I guess I'd need to create a hook, but the documentation about how I should do this is rather light, and after digging for a bit, I discovered that the markers seem can be edited as whole, not each of them individually:

With this code:

```
function my_theme_views_post_render (ViewExecutable $view, &$ouput)
{
  if ($view->id() === 'my_view') {
    dump($ouput['#rows']['#settings']);
  }
}
```

I get the following:

[image]

As you can see, the `marker_icon_path` key has an empty value. Also, when parsing each `$view->result`, I don't see anything that would allow me to change its marker.

Is there a way to change each marker individually?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Having a quick glance a the code it looks like you would need to subclass `Drupal\leaflet_views\Plugin\views\row\LeafletMarker`, and create the `alterLeafletMarker` method. The docs for that function say _For example, this can be used to add in icon configuration._ so it looks promising. You'd then implement [`hook_views_data_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data_alter/8.2.x) to replace the row handler class for the appropriate field type